# Remove column in UNION resultset, based on SUM of column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query which I paraphrase at the bottom of this question. It correctly gets a total score for a number of questions asked of people. So, resultsets looks like this:

```
            | David |  Bill  | Mary | James
Question 1  |   10  |   10   |  0   |   0
Question 2  |   10  |   20   |  0   |   0
Question 3  |   10  |   30   |  0   |   0
Question 4  |   0   |   20   |  0   |   1
```

What I need to do, and can't figure out, is how to remove any people from the resultset where they have zero marks for all of the questions asked. So, 'Mary' would be removed from the results above, leaving:

```
            | David |  Bill  | James
Question 1  |   10  |   10   |   0
Question 2  |   10  |   20   |   0
Question 3  |   10  |   30   |   0
Question 4  |   0   |   20   |   1
```

Here is the query which needs further developing:

```
SELECT
    `questions`,
    SUM(`0`) AS `David`,
    SUM(`1`) AS `Bill`
FROM(
(SELECT
    ROUND(((SUM(`sm`.`ScorecardMark`) * `sc`.`ScoreCriteriaWeight`)/(COUNT(`sm`.`ScorecardMark`) * `sc`.`ScoreCriteriaWeight`))*100) AS `0`,
    0 AS `1`
FROM
    `tables`
WHERE
    `clauses`
GROUP BY
    `questions`)
UNION
(SELECT
    0 AS `0`,
    ROUND(((SUM(`sm`.`ScorecardMark`) * `sc`.`ScoreCriteriaWeight`)/(COUNT(`sm`.`ScorecardMark`) * `sc`.`ScoreCriteriaWeight`))*100) AS `1`
FROM
    `tables`
WHERE
    `clauses`
GROUP BY
    `questions`)
)  AS `tbltotals`
GROUP BY
    `questions`
```

Comment: Data and data presentation are two separate things. But in any case you can do this in two queries. One query to get the columns you need, and another query to get the needed result.

Comment: I gather that in order to compose the query you need to know the list of people beforehand. Then why don't you get only those people who had some score? Then you can UNION only subqueries containing those people.

Comment: Agreed, Shedal, thanks for the lateral thinking and that's exactly what I've done.

Comment: Thanks Karolis too, you said the same thing.

Comment: @user783322: You can post your solution and accept it as an answer, and then others with a similar problem could see how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better approach would be to select questions as columns, as it should be easier to get the list of needed questions than getting a list of people who scored better than 0.

Then you can apply normal row-level filtering on people. And you can transpose the result to switch rows and columns in you application's code, in case you need that.